# Should we close questions about provider-documented error messages

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

As in the case of [Meaning of ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named os?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/185563/10919), some askers apparently don't bother to run a search of very straightforward error messages, even when accompanied by (non-999999) error codes.

In such cases, when the issue is already addressed sufficiently by the software provider/developer in easily accessible documentation, should the question be closed--perhaps as off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, but I am not sure which close reason you would use for it.  You could perhaps use the Other category and type in something unique.

Personally, I think the first action to take on questions that do not show sufficient research effort should be to downvote.

My next is to see if I can find a duplicate, because that way you would be using a standard close reason.

Sometimes, like in this instance, I found the expedient was to quickly answer it.  However, I would not advocate providing an answer as the first option to consider for such questions.

I saw some value in providing an answer referencing this particular Technical Article because it does not appear to have been mentioned on this site previously.